# Trouble installing glmmTMB

Tags: r, linux, installation, mixed-models, glmmtmb

I was using glmmTMB on a cluster. It was working for several weeks. I logged on today and it says I need to install glmmTMB. So, I tried that, but R is giving me the error below.

The main part says: **failed to lock directory.**

Thanks for any advice.

```
Installing package into ‘/home/xxxxxx/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/glmmTMB_1.1.2.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3910643 bytes (3.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.7 MB

ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/xxxxxx/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/xxxxxx/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-glmmTMB’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘glmmTMB’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpYJgfa7/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: what happens if you `rm -Rf /home/xxxxxx/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-glmmTMB` first? (or `sudo rm -Rf ...`) ?

Comment: if it's a cluster presumably you can't `sudo` (and presumably don't need to since the directory is under your home directory)